# NumPy einsum equivalent for XTensor (C++)

Tags: python, c++, numpy, xtensor

At the beginning, it's my very first question here, I'll really try my best to describe,
please note if I did it wrong.

Recently, I have been rewriting some numpy stuff to C++.
Circumstances required to do so, sadly. I really can't do anything about it.
(I can call some python commands from C++, but not everything.)

Naturally, I have started with XTensor, as it claims to be C++ equivalent of numpy.
Sadly, I've got stuck on `numpy.einsum`
I searched through the internet and found some related stuff, how it works (at least a bit).

Then comes my problem here. First of all, I need to implement the version without `->`.
Numpy docs are telling me that it's somewhat of 'implicit mode' (also with ellipsis then).
(Described later) I've found implementations / equivalents to some einsum configurations,
like `'i,ij'` and else.
I would like to stick with XTensor, since I've done quite much stuff already.
Here is the part of code I need to re-implement in XTensor with C++:

```py
# a is ndarray with shape (1, 28), 2dim
# e is ndarray with shape (1, 28, 3, 17), 4dim

numpy.einsum('...i,...ijk', a, e)
```

I hope that someone could explain me, what does it refer to.
And it would be best if you could give me some idea how could I implement it.
I can use anything, I think… what actually will end up as `xt::xarray` at the end.
I was thinking about calling python code from C++ or even using Google protobuf, in worst case.

If you have any ideas or useful links, please share!
(related to code i posted and not to `numpy.einsum` in general)

Comment: In that example, the `i` is the 28 shared dimension, `jk` the following dimansions of `e`.  The `...` means it can work any leading dimensions (here just 1) as long as they match.  Since `i` is shared, its the `sum` dimension for the `sum-of-products`.  The result will be (1,3,17), '...jk'.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, that helped me a bit to understand how it works. Either, I would be very thankful if you could tell me what is it doing with `a`. I mean, what is it creating a dot product from, if it loops over dimension `i`? I am still quite new to numpy, any help will be appreciated for sure. (numpy docs are just 'quickly running' over it)

Comment: That's what I mean by `sum-of-products`.  A conventional `np.dot` is 'ij,jk->ik', where the `j` is shared dimension that is summed.  `einsum` generalizes the notion, allowing us to work with more dimensions.

Comment: Unfortunately einsum is still missing for xtensor... It is high on my wishlist, but one needs the time to implement. Anyway, a workaround for a specific tensor operation is possible, I do this by using the fact that your 'tensors' are stored contiguously. My workaournd functions are available here: https://github.com/tdegeus/GMatTensor